# Nginx container does not send requests to back-end

Tags: angular, nginx, docker-compose

I created a docker-compose.yml file and created three services:

- asana_back: spring-boot on port 8080;
- asana_database: mysql on port 3306;
- asana_front: nginx on port 80;

I added them to a network called call-asana-network.

In the docker-compose.yml file I set the name of the containers in the field `container_name` so that the names are used internally by the containers, however, in the communication between the front that is in nginx can not communicate with the back and and show the error `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` in he browser. I believe it is the nginx configuration file but I don't know what it can be.

I don't know if it matters, but the front system is Angular 7.

Environment.prod.ts code:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  serverApiURL: "http://asana_back:8080/api"
};
```

Docker-compose code:

```
version: '3'

services:
  back:
    image: openjdk:8-jre
    container_name: asana_back
    restart: always
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./server-spring:/server-spring
    command: java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod /server-spring/system.war
    ports:
      - "8888:8080"
    networks:
      - call-asana-network
  front:
    image: nginx:1.17
    container_name: asana_front
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8980:80"
    volumes:
      - ./server-nginx/www:/var/www
      - ./server-nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - call-asana-network
  database:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: asana_database
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: fWXDA0UCYnbf7Rr95hyt
      MYSQL_DATABASE: call_asana
    tty: true
    networks:
      - call-asana-network
    ports:
      - "3366:3306"
    restart: always

# Docker network
networks:
  call-asana-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Nginx app.conf code:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

Header data entered by browser Chrome:

```
Request URL: http://asana_back:8080/api/project
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Accept: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:8980
Referer: http://localhost:8980/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Who is `asana_call`?

Comment: It was a mistake, I changed to asana_back which is correct, but the problem remains the same. I believe it is the nginx configuration, I keep making changes and testing but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand in your post, you have an Angular front-end application that connects to a back-end application, both running in Docker containers.

The Angular application, being a Javascript application, gets executed by the browser so on the host. Not in a container. When the javascript code is executed (so on the host), it calls your api (back-end application). So the call to the API is initiated on the host, who doesn't know who `asana_back` is. Only docker-compose and the Docker  containers know that.

Therefore your Angular configuration needs to change to:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  serverApiURL: "http://localhost:8888/api"
};
```

The rest of the setup looks good but if it still doesn't work let me know. It should work thou.

Comment: It was a fool mistake, requests are made in the web browser and not in Nginx! Thank you!